# What is the etymology of the toponym Carentan?

Tags: étymologie, france, toponymes

What is the etymology of the toponym [*Carentan*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carentan) (a small rural town near the north-eastern base of the French Cotentin Peninsula in Normandy)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En consultant [wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carentan) on lit :

> La localité est désignée à l'époque gallo-romaine sous la forme Carentomagus qui serait issue de l'anthroponyme gaulois Carentus, ou du substantif carento, « cher », « beau », et de magos, « marché ».

Comment: Juste pour finasser un peu... car Wiki n'est pas très fiable pour ce genre de recherches et trop souvent approximatif dans ses orthographes. Je ne sais donc dire quel Romain s'est insinué dans l'histoire pour forcer ainsi sa déclinaison mais... comme beaucoup de noms gaulois et... particulièrement de Normandie... (Rotomag**O**s, Argentomag**O**s...) c'est bien de Carentomag**O**s dont il s'agit. Une publication plus fiable et, au demeurant intéressante à voir ici : https://www.persee.fr/doc/annor_0003-4134_2006_num_56_4_1591 DEIX AIE! ;)

Comment: Au passage du document ci-dessus, on pourra alors découvrir que le *magos* en question recouvre une étendue probablement plus vaste qu'un seul marché.